# How to select word in a pdf file

Tags: android, pdf

In my app I am using the library https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer for reading a pdf file. Now I want to select words from the pdf file, how will I do it?

Answer (score 2):

What the library you're using actually does is to basically convert an PDF file into a Bitmap image so that it can be viewed and zoomed etc. Therefore you cannot select text or words from the PDF file, or the resulting Bitmap image for that matter.

Comment: So could you please tell me how I will be able to select a text in a pdf file?

Comment: @souvik Unfortunately I don't know the answer to that question - I knew how to answer your original question however;p